# Why does git revert complain about a missing -m option?

Tags: git, github, git-revert

So I'm working on a project with other people, and there's multiple github forks being worked on. Someone just made a fix for a problem and I merged with his fork, but then I realized that I could find a better solution. I want to revert the commit I just made. I tried doing this with `git revert HEAD` but it gave me this error:

```
fatal: Commit <SHA1> is a merge but no -m option was given.
```

What does that mean? When I merged and committed, I did use the -m option to say "Merged with <username>".

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 367):

By default `git revert` refuses to revert a merge commit as what that actually means is ambiguous. I presume that your `HEAD` is in fact a merge commit.

If you want to revert the merge commit, you have to specify which parent of the merge you want to consider to be the main trunk, i.e. what you want to revert to.

Often this will be parent number one, for example if you were on `master` and did `git merge unwanted` and then decided to revert the merge of `unwanted`. The first parent would be your pre-merge `master` branch and the second parent would be the tip of `unwanted`.

In this case you could do:

```
git revert -m 1 HEAD
```

`git cat-file -p [MERGE_COMMIT_ID]` will show the parent branches in order. The first one listed would be -m 1, the second -m 2.

Comment: OK thanks. I found it easier just to change the two files that were affected by the merge and then commit some of my other changes too.

Comment: Where can I find information whether I have to use -m1 or -m2, ...?

Comment: `git cat-file -p [MERGE_COMMIT_ID]` will show the parent branches in order.  The first one listed would be `-m 1`, the second `-m 2`.

Comment: `git revert [HASH] -m 2` is telling me 
On branch 1.x-1.x
nothing to commit, working directory clean but my commit is not reverted.

Comment: the same is true of `git revert 731a400e53381010ec617 -m2` (with no space)

Comment: What I did to determine what number to give with `-m` was to simply try `git revert -m 1 thecommithash` and check if the diff looked right. If not, get rid of the revert (with a `git reset --hard commit_before_revert`) and try again with `-m 2`.

Comment: So if I need to revert back past 10 merges (which is quite likely since git performs a merge automatically everytime I pull in changes from another developer) I have to do this for every single merge? Is this why git fans are so keen on rebasing, because revert is basically useless?

Comment: This is BY FAR the best explanation for this. This should be marked as the answer

Comment: what's all the "m" stuff? I dont see any "m 1" or "m 2" when I run `git cat-file -p SOMECOMMIT`. I see 3 lines labeled: tree, parent, parent.

Comment: "what that actually means is ambiguous" - I disagree.  If I'm on `branch-b` and merge in some commits from `branch-a`, this results in modified content on `branch-b`, and no modification on `branch-a`.  The only sensible thing "revert" can mean in this context is "undo the modifications made to `branch-b`".  There's zero ambiguity.

Comment: Is there any canonical source that clearly explains what numbering system is understood by the --mainline flag?  The documentation is (to me) a bit vague: "This option specifies the parent number (starting from 1) of the mainline and allows revert to reverse the change relative to the specified parent"

Answer (score 61):

Say the other guy created bar on top of foo, but you created baz in the meantime and then merged, giving a history of

```
$ git lola
*   2582152 (HEAD, master) Merge branch 'otherguy'
|\  
| * c7256de (otherguy) bar
* | b7e7176 baz
|/  
* 9968f79 foo
```

Note: [git lola](http://blog.kfish.org/2010/04/git-lola.html) is a non-standard but useful alias.

No dice with `git revert`:

```
$ git revert HEAD
fatal: Commit 2582152... is a merge but no -m option was given.
```

Charles Bailey gave an [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5971033/123109) as usual. Using `git revert` as in

```
$ git revert --no-edit -m 1 HEAD
[master e900aad] Revert "Merge branch 'otherguy'"
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 bar
```

effectively deletes `bar` and produces a history of

```
$ git lola
* e900aad (HEAD, master) Revert "Merge branch 'otherguy'"
*   2582152 Merge branch 'otherguy'
|\  
| * c7256de (otherguy) bar
* | b7e7176 baz
|/  
* 9968f79 foo
```

But I suspect you want to *throw away* the merge commit:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD^
HEAD is now at b7e7176 baz

$ git lola
* b7e7176 (HEAD, master) baz
| * c7256de (otherguy) bar
|/  
* 9968f79 foo
```

As documented in the [`git rev-parse` manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html)

> **`<rev>^`, e.g. HEAD^, `v1.5.1^0`**
>   A suffix `^` to a revision parameter means the first parent of that commit object. `^<n>` means the *n*-th parent (*i.e.* `<rev>^` is equivalent to `<rev>^1`). As a special rule, `<rev>^0` means the commit itself and is used when `<rev>` is the object name of a tag object that refers to a commit object.

so before invoking `git reset`, `HEAD^` (or `HEAD^1`) was b7e7176 and `HEAD^2` was c7256de, *i.e.*, respectively the first and second parents of the merge commit.

Be careful with `git reset --hard` because it can destroy work.

Comment: It's a mixed up, muddled up, shook up world. Except for Lola. Thanks a million for this fantastic alias.

Comment: Easy way to Add `lola` to your git commands: `git config --global alias.lola "log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all"`

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem, the solution was to look at the commit graph (using gitk) and see that I had the following:

```
*   commit I want to cherry-pick (x)
|\  
| * branch I want to cherry-pick to (y)
* | 
|/  
* common parent (x)
```

I understand now that I want to do

```
git cherry-pick -m 2 mycommitsha
```

This is because `-m 1` would merge based on the common parent where as `-m 2` merges based on branch y, that is the one I want to cherry-pick to.

Comment: Possibly because it's not related to `git-revert`, which is what this question is about.

Comment: I think this question is about the `-m` option, not exclusively about `git merge`. I.e., the reasoning behind the use of the `-m` option would seem to be similar for reverts and cherry-picks. If that's not true, please let us know. Since I haven't found any other questions that specifically address the cherry-pick use of it, thanks for this answer, which probably led google to help me find this question and useful, relevant discussion!

Comment: If I understand correctly, git has no record of which branch (y) was made on; as far as it knows, your picture is symmetric: the unnamed commit on the left branch isn't any better or worse than the one on the right (y) in any way.  If that's correct, how does it decide which is 1 and which is 2?

Answer (score 3):

In the original question, the '-m option' of the git error was probably mistaken to denote a commit message. As explained in the other answers, use '-m n' to specify the nth parent of the merge to pick the parent you consider to be the main trunk.