# Git revert is a merge but no -m option was provided

Tags: git

I am trying to revert a commit on protected master branch using

```
   git revert <hash number>
```

but get an error

```
error: commit <hash number> is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: revert failed
```

I tried to understand documentation for -m option [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) but I do not understand it entirely. How can I get around this error?

Comment: I looked for some earlier answers that might describe *why* there is a `-m` option, and the best I found is https://stackoverflow.com/a/5971033/1256452. Does that suffice, and if not, how much do you want to know about revert? :-)

Comment: Great. This solved my issue